# Conditional formatting on block of cells using once cell value and then copying multiple times

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Hoping I can get some help with this.

I need to apply conditional formatting to a block of cells (E21:F27) based on one cell value condition (E23>0), which I can do. I then need to copy this 'block' multiple times across, which I've managed to do too - using 2 conditional format rules:

[Conditional Formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hR8e.jpg)

[Rows to be copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDsFp.jpg)

I now want to copy & paste rows 21-27 and have the conditional formats update the row numbers automatically.

If this possible? I have googled my little heart out but can't find anything on it...

Your help is much appreciated!!! :)

Comment: try losing `$` sign in front of the row number such as:  `=$E21:$E27` than try to copy-paste.

Comment: Thanks ctumturk. It was more that the single cell (E23) does not update to the new row number in the conditional format. I have to use an absolute reference to the row number otherwise the cells in the 'block' will look at the wrong cell. Sorry I'm not really up on technical lingo - I'm sure you can tell.

Comment: I've found I can apply conditional formatting to each individual cell within the block. And then I can copy and paste without an issue. I think this may be the only option! Just a bit laborious :)